# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS overheating after upgrading from Ubuntu 19

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, overheating

I have just upgraded my machine from Ubuntu 19 to 20.04 LTS and it started overheating. Ubuntu 19 was working fine and the upgrade has not changed my configuration files (i.e. the turbo is still disabled and the cpu governor is still *powersave*). Also, tlp is installed.

The temperature I got upon running `sudo tlp-stat -t` was `52-58 °C` on Ubuntu 19, while it is now `65-75 °C`. The laptop gets especially hot when watching YouTube videos on firefox. When it gets hot, it starts lagging as well.

A bit of context:
Soon after I upgraded, I got rid of the `nouveau` drivers, with which there was serious lag, and I installed `nvidia 440` drivers. I also tried `nvidia 390`, while I have not tried `nvidia 435`. `nvidia 440` gives very good perfomance while `nvidia 390` is very laggy. Also, I noticed that my touchpad doesn't work with `440` but it works with `390`.
Finally, the kernel version on my machine is `5.4.0-29-generic`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Fresh, see this page, I had the same problem and it fixed it:  https://itsfoss.com/reduce-overheating-laptops-linux/

Comment: @Ollie What exactly did you do? I already have tlp installed... I think I will try cpufreq alongside it and then come back to post updates.

Answer (score 2):

Under volting helps a lot when there is over heating (and by lot I mean A LOT). To be on a safer side, manufacturers supply higher voltage than required to the CPU (which causes heating), as at very lower voltages CPU doesn't work properly under stress. Under volting is completely safe. It will not void your warranty whatsoever. Under volting is basically removing the excess voltage supplied and giving the minimum voltage required to run the CPU smoothly.

Try `intel-undervolt` from [here on GitHub](https://github.com/kitsunyan/intel-undervolt).

[Here](https://miloserdov.org/?p=1932) is an article on CPU undervolting in Linux which I followed

Some terms in the guide might be deprecated. Refer to the first link for the deprecated terms.

Here is a step by step procedure with the non deprecated terms

1. install git with `sudo apt install git`
2. run `git clone https://github.com/kitsunyan/intel-undervolt`
3. `sudo su` and then enter password
4. run `./configure --enable-systemd --enable-openrc && make && make install`
5. close the root mode by typing `exit` and press enter
6. run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
7. run `sudo gedit /etc/intel-undervolt.conf` this will open a text editor
8. change the value in line 10 (in front of CPU) to -130 like this `undervolt 0 'CPU' -130` (recommended -125)
9. now save that text file and exit
10. run `sudo intel-undervolt apply` and then run `sudo systemctl start intel-undervolt`
11. use the system for some time, if it looks stable then run `sudo systemctl enable intel-undervolt`.

As of selecting the offset, I use `undervolt 0 'CPU' -130` in the `/etc/intel-undervolt.conf` file. As a beginner I would suggest you to stick to undervolting the CPU only.

To find the correct offset (unique to each CPU piece. Same CPU but on different computer could have different ideal offset) slowly  lower the offset by small values (I used 10), and at the point where your PC crashes, is the threshold. And set the final value to threshold - 10. In my case it crashed at 140 so I set it to 130.

The only downside (if you don't choose `sudo systemctl enable intel-undervolt`) is that you will have to apply the settings on every boot. I have created an alias with `alias us='sudo intel-undervolt apply && sudo tlp start'`. So I just have to type `us` in the terminal on a boot, and then I am good to go.

**Note:** the crashing of PC to calculate the offset is completely safe. It will not damage you hardware whatsoever.

**Note:** Any Intel CPU can go to -125 at least, above that comes the difficult part. If you want to take it to the limit, then only try increasing it step by step. Otherwise -125 will work just fine for any Intel CPU.

You could also try to switch to intel integrated graphics card.

1. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime`
2. Reboot
3. `sudo prime-select intel`
4. Reboot

and we are done.

Comment: @fresh I have done some edits. Do check the step by step guide.